# Search an Replace in a huge XML file

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have a large (750mb) XML file.
I would like to replace the string

```
file://localhost/E:/
```

with the following string

```
file:///Volumes/TOSHIBA%20EXT/
```

it appears throughout the xml file in a line like this:

```
<key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/E:/etc.mp3</string>
```

I am on windows, I tried xml validator tools, but the file is too large to manipulate in memory ... even with 16gb installed.

Something is needed that can stream the file and save the changes .. Sed seems incredibly awkward, could someone show me an xmlstarlet command that would accomplish this?
Thanks guys

Comment: What about XSLT?

Comment: Please show valid XML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

steep learning curve there, I asked chatgpt and it gave me this code for xmlstarlet

```
xml ed -L --subnode '//string[text()="file://localhost/E:/"]' -t text -n 'file:///Volumes/TOSHIBA%20EXT/' books.xml > output.xml
```

which quickly ran out of memory, despite the -L, in the end I split the file into manageable chunks ran a search & replace and then rejoined them. Don't know why I didnt think of that in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

With a streaming XSLT 3.0 processor such as Saxon-EE you could do:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="string/text()[.='file://localhost/E:/']">
    <xsl:text>file:///Volumes/TOSHIBA%20EXT/</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```